# How to use AzurePowerShell task in Azure Devops Linux self hosted agents?

Tags: linux, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am trying to run a Powershell script in Azure DevOps pipelines.
Since the script uses `Az` module commands, we decided to use  `AzurePowerShell@5` task in the pipeline.

As mentioned [in this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-powershell-v5?view=azure-pipelines):

> By default, Azure PowerShell v5 uses PowerShell Core for Linux agents

Since we have self-hosted Linux agents, it is necessary to manually install **PowerShell Core** and Az modules on the agent before using `AzurePowerShell@5`.

Followed [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/install-ubuntu?view=powershell-7.4#installation-via-direct-download) steps to install powershell core and the steps mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azps-linux?view=azps-11.1.0#installation) to install `Az` module.

```
# Install powershell core
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y wget apt-transport-https software-properties-common
wget -q "https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/packages-microsoft-prod.deb"
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y powershell

# Install Az Module
Install-Module -Name Az -Repository PSGallery -RequiredVersion '11.1.0' -Force 
Update-Module -Name Az -Force
```

But when we use the task in the pipeline,

```
 - task: AzurePowerShell@5
    name: test_script
    displayName: 'test_script'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: $(arm_service_connection)
      ScriptType: 'FilePath'
      ScriptPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/powershell_scripts/test_script.ps1
      ScriptArguments: >
        -subscriptionId $(subscription_id)
      azurePowerShellVersion: 'OtherVersion'
      preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: '11.1.0'
      FailOnStandardError: true
      pwsh: true
```

it gives an error:

```
Generating script.
/usr/bin/pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command . '/agent/_work/_temp/f3210d6a-92eb-4665-92bd-9c6790840726.ps1'
File saved!
Exception: /agent/_work/_tasks/AzurePowerShell_72a1931b-effb-4d2e-8fd8-f8472a07cb62/5.231.0/Utility.ps1:94
Line |
  94 |  …             throw ("Could not find the module path with given version …
     |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Could not find the module path with given version.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
##[error]PowerShell wrote one or more lines to the standard error stream.
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a blog [here](https://bzzzt.io/post/2021-01/2021-01-13-azure-powershell-task-self-hosted/) that explains the same. I also checked the [file](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzurePowerShellV5/Utility.ps1#L94) that was mentioned in the error.

It is evident that the `AzurePowerShell@5` task is looking for the `Az` module files at a path `/usr/share/az_<azurePowerShellVersion>`.

So, I installed the module in the correct path using the following script and it worked:

```
# Install powershell core
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y wget apt-transport-https software-properties-common
wget -q "https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/packages-microsoft-prod.deb"
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y powershell

# Install Az Module in correct path
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/az_11.1.0
sudo /usr/bin/pwsh -Command 'Find-Module -Name Az -RequiredVersion '11.1.0' -Repository 'PSGallery' | Save-Module -Path '/usr/share/az_11.1.0' -Force -Verbose'
```

Make sure the ado agent user has `read` and `execute` permissions on that module directory and files.

Specifying these parameters for the task is important to pick up the correct version:

```
azurePowerShellVersion: 'OtherVersion'
preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: '11.1.0'
```

Comment: Glad to know that you have found the solution to solve the issue. You can accept your answer. This will be helpful to other users who have the same issue.

Comment: I had the same issue and on my end the solution has quite different script as I run it from portal "run command. Added "Install-Module" instead of "Find-Module" (had error with find-module) and added -Force. Thank you!"

`sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/az_11.1.0
sudo /usr/bin/pwsh -Command 'Install-Module -Name Az -RequiredVersion '11.1.0' -Repository 'PSGallery -Force' | Save-Module -Path '/usr/share/az_11.1.0' -Force -Verbose'`